# Is there a succinct way in ruby to return the array itself when the array is not empty

Tags: ruby

Basically I'd like to check the array AND set it to a variable if its NOT empty at the same time:
In the same way that I can assign a variable while checking a boolean, I'd like to be able to do this with an array. E.g :

```
bar = "hello world"
if foo = bar.is_a?(String)
   puts foo
end

=> "hello world"



bar = [1,2,3]
if foo = !bar.empty?
  puts foo
end

=> 
1
2
3
```

Comment: And what is it supposed to return if it’s not empty? IMO, this feels like over-[golfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) it.

Comment: I would like the array itself to be returned instead of true

Comment: Sorry I meant “what is it supposed to return if it *is* empty”.

Comment: If i'm thinking about this correctly then returning false would be the best, but you may be right in that i'm over golfing. It seems like I run into this case once in a while where I have to first check the array then store it to another variable if it exists.

Comment: What doesn’t make sense to me is why you wouldn’t just continue using the same variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
my_array = array.empty? ? do_something(array) : array
```

Comment: I'd like to get the array back if its NOT empty. Also, this will return the results of do_something, not the array itself.

Comment: Ok, I've just updated my answer to something that returns the original array if not empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.empty?
```

to check if it is empty.

```
do_sth if array.empty?
```

Comment: I would like to immediately store the value of the array to a variable if its NOT empty. empty? returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

there is the `||=` operator.

It works in this way:

```
var ||= 1
# is equivalent of:
var = var || 1
```

And returns the value of `var`.

So, you can do something like:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array ||= do_something
# array is NOT changed

array = nil
array ||= do_something
# array is set to the return value of do_something, and the same value is returned.
```

Comment: Empty array (`[]`) != `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you need something like this

```
bar = [1,2,3]
p bar.empty? ? [1] : bar #=> [1,2,3]

bar = []
p bar.empty? ? [1] : bar #=> [1]
```